# How to Get a Boolean from Another Table in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I am trying to fetch a value based on the median value of another columns, I am trying two different ways one of them yield results and other does not. Can you please tell me what is the difference in two codes?

**Code1:**

```
med = df2['% Renewable'].median()

for x in df2['% Renewable']:
    if med >= x:
        df2['median'] = 0
    else:
        df2['median'] = 1
```

**Code 2:**

```
df2['median1'] = [1 if x>=med else 0 for x in df2['% Renewable']]
```

Comment: In the first code you're setting `df2['median']` to either 1 or 0 (repeatedly). In the second code, you're setting it to a sequence of values.

Comment: In the first case, despite iterating over the values the assignments assign the **entire** column, so you’ll assign everything a 1 or zero based on the last value

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df2['median'] = df2['% Renewable'].ge(df2['% Renewable'].median()).astype(int)
```

Alternatve:

```
df2['median'] = np.where(df2['% Renewable'].ge(df2['% Renewable'].median()), 1, 0)
```

**Your error**

your problem is that here in each iteration modifies al value of  your  `df2['median']` serie. But to do this task you do not need to use a loop for, the use of loops here is not recommended, since questions is unnecessary and slows down code

```
for x in df2['% Renewable']:
    if med >= x:
        df2['median'] = 0
    else:
        df2['median'] = 1
```

here the value assigned to the whole series depends only on the last value of the series (the value with which the loop ends)